# getting this tailwind css warning in my project not getting what to do

Tags: angular, typescript, import, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I was working on live project which was in angular now im no longer part of it , after some month im trying to open this project im getting this tailwind css warning

```
./src/styles.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!
./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!
./src/styles.css - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Warning

(213:1) postcss-import: @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset or empty @layer)
```

i try and checked but in output im not getting anything , everything is blank tailwind css is not working
if you have any idea please let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you say everything is blank, do you mean that you do not have tailwind imported at all into your style.css file? You should have this in your style.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And since you have the postcss plugin installed, you should have some sort of @import in your style.css as well, above the @tailwind directives. If you are not using the postcss, remove the import from your angular.json if there is one.